# MATLAB : How to build 4d plot per levels

Tags: matlab, plot, 4d

I need to build a graph as shown, only need to be displayed at different levels of other plots. I found this:

```
m = 10;
n = 25;
d = 4;
S = rand([m,n,d]);
slice(S, [], [], 1:size(S,3));
```

[image]

Can we instead S transmit another plot for example `contour()`, to get different graphs at different levels as shown above? And if so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at `contourslice`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourslice.html ?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need, i found [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html), but here for build used a three-dimensional matrix. How I can put in it my contour plots? In  the end I need to get something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/volvis_mri3a.png)

Comment: Your example link seems quite comprehensive. Perhaps update your question to show your attempt at implementing that example and tell us where you are having trouble?

Comment: At the moment the problem is how to generate matrix D according to my task.

Comment: It looks to me like their D and your S are in the same format. Post code showing your actual problem or no one can help you

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from your own link:

```
m = 10;
n = 25;
d = 4;
S = rand([m,n,d]);
contourslice(S, [], [], 1:size(S,3),10);
view(3);
```